# How to stick an overlay to user location with MapKit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, mkoverlay

I created a mapView which find user's location and draws a green circle overlay around the user but I could not make a way to stick this green circle to user wether user is moving or stationary.
All of my tries led to either make a tail of these circles after user or just one circle from user's first location.

In my viewDidLoad() I also initiated an instance of location manager which is where I get my location data from.

You can see my location manager delegate below.

my didUpdateLocations is:

```
//CLLocationManager Delegate
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    //create array of locations of user
    var locationArray = locations as NSArray
    //find the last object of location
    var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
    //creating circle
    var newCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: locationObj.coordinate, radius: 100 as CLLocationDistance)
    if locations.count>1 {
        //I tried dispatch but still tail of green circles
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_t(), { () -> Void in
        self.treesMap.removeOverlay(newCircle)
        })
    }

     self.treesMap.addOverlay(newCircle)        
    //if location determination is fixed
    if  locationFixAchieved == false {
    //declare that location is fixed locationManager.location.coordinate
        locationFixAchieved = true

        var prevLocation = centreLocation
        self.centreLocationCoordinate = (locationObj.coordinate as CLLocationCoordinate2D)
            println("location changed")

        //for output purpose
        println("locations = \(locations)")                

     }

}
```

my renderForOverlay function is:

```
/circle overlay function
func mapView(
    mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay   overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        //if the overlay was type of circle
        if (overlay.isKindOfClass(MKCircle))
        {
            //declaring circleRenderer variable
            var circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            //setting stroke color of the circle
            circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            //setting fill color of cirlce
            circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor(
                red: 0,
                green: 1.0,
                blue: 0,
                alpha: 0.5)
            //return rendererForOverlay function
            return circleRenderer
        }
        //if overlay was not type of MKCircle
        return nil
}
```

I'm looking for a way that I can make the circle overlay stick to the users location all the time and move by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section of code:

```
var newCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: locationObj.coordinate, radius: 100 as CLLocationDistance)
if locations.count>1 {
    //I tried dispatch but still tail of green circles
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_t(), { () -> Void in
    self.treesMap.removeOverlay(newCircle)
    })
}

self.treesMap.addOverlay(newCircle)
```

the `removeOverlay` line (if it even executes) does not remove the previous circle overlay.

Instead, it tries to remove some *new instance* of a circle overlay (`newCircle`) which hasn't even been added to the map -- the line will essentially do nothing.

Since the only overlay you want on the map is the single circle, before adding the new one, you can just call `removeOverlays` (plural) and tell the map to remove all existing overlays.

Example:

```
var newCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: locationObj.coordinate, radius: 100 as CLLocationDistance)

/* comment this block out -- don't need it
if locations.count>1 {
    //I tried dispatch but still tail of green circles
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_t(), { () -> Void in
    self.treesMap.removeOverlay(newCircle)
    })
}
*/

self.treesMap.removeOverlays(self.treesMap.overlays)

self.treesMap.addOverlay(newCircle)
```

Comment: thnx for reply. It removed the first circle but I didn't see any circle while user started moving or after when stopped